# how to stop the native android service playing music

Tags: android, service, media-player

I am developing a media app.
If a user plays a song with the native android application for playing a song and then opens my application then i want to stop playing that song in background before user opens my application. At present both songs are being played at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not "stop playing that song in background before user opens my application". You [request the audio focus using `AudioManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#requestAudioFocus%28android.media.AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener,%20int,%20int%29).

Comment: i wrote the code AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
   manager.requestAudioFocus(new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
   
   public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
   }
  }, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
  and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

You can have your program run the isPlaying() routine check if something is playing and take action against the media player if needed.

Comment: I dont think so that is possible when playing with the native android service. After getting the AudioManager object i can jus use its methods